# Sonatype Nexus: "Remove Releases from Repository" isn't consistent with configuration

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I set up the `Remove releases from repository` task in my Sonatype Nexus instance. I asked it to keep 10 versions.

I ran it and some versions were deleted, but many more than 10 were kept. Also the ones that were deleted didn't seem to follow any specific pattern. Some releases were kept that were older than ones that got deleted.

Nexus version 2.6.4-02.

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you select a specific repository while scheduling this task?

Comment: yes, I selected a specific repository.

Comment: Try after a reindexing and rebuild metadata. sometimes it fixes this issue that I have seen before. Also try running the indexing manually to make sure the results are good, before you schedule it.

Comment: just tried that - unfortunately it didn't work :( is there a chance that these builds are being filtered out by any reason? maybe metadata? I did select `All (Any Repository)` in the repository target parameter

Comment: I believe you have more than one repository in your system. In that case you should be specifying the "specific repository" instead of "All the repositories". And then try the same thing. reindex and rebuild meta data

Comment: I have actually selected the specific repo on the repository section, but selected `All (Any Repository)` in the **repository target**. See the image here: https://postimg.org/image/3vsubaduf/